# Question about sending automatic bulk mail in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

I have a database in SQL Server that has a `user` table with 3 columns: name, date of birth and email.

I have a stored procedure that goes through this table looking for who is having a birthday today, and sends him a congratulatory email, so far it works at 100.

However, I want to add within the same procedure that I send an email to all the users of the database (except the one with a birthday), notifying them that x person are having a birthday today.

This is my current SQL Server code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSendEmail
AS
    DECLARE @email nvarchar(128)
    DECLARE @name  nvarchar(128)
    DECLARE @Date  date

    SELECT 
        GETDATE(), 
        MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())

    DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT u.name, u.email
        FROM dbo.users u
        WHERE MONTH(u.dateofbirth) = MONTH(GETDATE())
          AND DAY(u.dateofbirth) = DAY(GETDATE()) 

    OPEN email_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @name, @email

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @email

        DECLARE @subject nvarchar(255)
        DECLARE @Bodytext nvarchar(512)

        SET @BodyText = @Name + '' + 'we wish you happy birthday'
        SET @Subject = 'Happy Birthday' 

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                      @profile_name = 'Birthday Alert',
                      @recipients = @email,
                      @body = @Bodytext,
                      @subject = @subject;

        FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @name, @email
    END 

    CLOSE email_cursor
    DEALLOCATE email_cursor
```

Comment: You simply change your where clause to be `not(month... and day... )`

Comment: Let's rephrase that approach! I want to leak important personal information to strangers that may or may not know certain individuals. Nor have these certain individuals requested or agreed to such leaking of personal information. Before you consider HOW to do this, consider if you SHOULD do this.

Comment: This procedure is for a small organization. They are not unknown

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSendEmail AS
DECLARE @email nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @name  nvarchar(128)
DECLARE @Date  date
DECLARE @Num_Users_Having_Birthday varchar(100) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.users WHERE MONTH(u.dateofbirth) = MONTH(GETDATE())
      AND DAY(u.dateofbirth) = DAY(GETDATE()))

SELECT 
    GETDATE(), 
    MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())

DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT u.name, u.email
    FROM dbo.users u
    WHERE MONTH(u.dateofbirth) <> MONTH(GETDATE())
      AND DAY(u.dateofbirth) <> DAY(GETDATE()) 

OPEN email_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @name, @email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT @email

    DECLARE @subject nvarchar(255)
    DECLARE @Bodytext nvarchar(512)

    SET @BodyText = @Name
    SET @Subject = 'Number of People having Birthday today:' + @Num_Users_Having_Birthday

    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                  @profile_name = 'Birthday Alert',
                  @recipients = @email,
                  @body = @Bodytext,
                  @subject = @subject;

    FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @name, @email
END 

CLOSE email_cursor
DEALLOCATE email_cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spSendEmail
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @email nvarchar(128)
    DECLARE @name  nvarchar(128)
    DECLARE @has_birthday BIT
    DECLARE @Date  date
    DECLARE @birthday_boys INT -- update this to 

    SELECT 
        GETDATE(), 
        MONTH(GETDATE()), DAY(GETDATE()), YEAR(GETDATE())

    IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..users') IS NOT NULL)
        DROP TABLE #users;

    -- For Sql Server version >= 2016: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #users

    SELECT u.name, u.email
        , IIF(MONTH(u.dateofbirth) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(u.dateofbirth) = DAY(GETDATE()),1,0) has_birthday 
    INTO #users
    FROM dbo.users u

    --Get all birthday boys list

    SELECT  @birthday_boys = COUNT(u.name)
    FROM #users u
    WHERE has_birthday = 1

    DECLARE email_cursor CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT u.name, u.email, u.has_birthday
        FROM #users
    OPEN email_cursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @name, @email, @has_birthday

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        PRINT @email

        DECLARE @subject nvarchar(255)
        DECLARE @Bodytext nvarchar(512)

        SET @BodyText = IIF(@has_birthday = 1, @Name + '' + 'we wish you happy birthday', CONCAT('Birthday boys'' count is ', @birthday_boys))  
        SET @Subject = IIF(@has_birthday = 1, 'Happy Birthday', 'Birthday Boys'' Count') 

        EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
                      @profile_name = 'Birthday Alert',
                      @recipients = @email,
                      @body = @BodyText,
                      @subject = @subject


        FETCH NEXT FROM email_cursor INTO @name, @email
    END 

    CLOSE email_cursor
    DEALLOCATE email_cursor

    IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..users') IS NOT NULL)
        DROP TABLE #users;
    -- For Sql Server version >= 2016: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #users

END
```